# How do you use "alguna que otra cosa" in context?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

How do you use "alguna que otra cosa" in context? What does this phrase mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por ejemplo:

> *Tengo que comprar alguna que otra cosa* = I have to buy some things
>
> *Veo alguna que otra película* = I see the ocassional movie / I see a movie every once and a while.